# Im trying to get the index of element if the user input number is present in the array. But when give the input i get he same number as output

Tags: arrays, indexing, element

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RemoveElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int [] myarray2 = {1,2,3,4,15,6,7,8,9,34,50};
        
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter you no form 1 to 9");
        int num2 = input2.nextInt();                
        
        for (int i = 0; i < myarray2.length; i++) {
            if( num2 == i) {
                    myarray2 [i] = (myarray2[i - 1]);
                    System.out.println(myarray2[i]);
```